# How to display both the output window and the debug console simultaneously?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to ***simultaneously*** view the output window ***and*** the debug console in VSCode?

Comment: so far no one found an answer for this? I'm also interested.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible after

- [VS Code 1.42 (January 2020)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_42#_moving-the-panel) which allowed the "*panel, which holds the Output, Debug Console, Terminal, and Problems panes*" to be "*moved to the left side of the editor*".
- [VS Code 1.46 (May 2020)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_46#_flexible-layout) which allowed

  - "*Moving views between Side Bar and Panel*"

    > Perhaps you would prefer a view from the Side Bar to be located in the Panel or vice versa. To do this, you can now drag a view by its header or an entire group by its icon or title from its current placement and move it to the desired location.
  - "*Grouping views*"

    > You might also want to group some views together that come from different extensions or you feel the default groups of built-in views aren't quite right for you. You can both move views into existing groups or create new groups for a select set of views. This works across the Side Bar and Panel just as before.

With those improvements, you can move the **Output** tab to the left side and the **Debug Console** to the bottom (or vice-versa) and view them both at the same time. While at it, it's also nice to have a separate view of the **Variables** tab, and now all 3 can be viewed at the same time.

[image]