# How to show both internal terminal and debug console in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I need to debug a program on a server and would like to still have its output in GDB.
The following "works" in general:

- manual started (terminal) task that opens a ssh connection, does the necessary pre-setup (server-side scripts), then runs `gdbserver --multi :12345`
- GDB debug configuration that runs in attach mode and executes the appropriate command chain `"set sysroot remote:", "target extended-remote myserver:12345", "set remote exec-file /path/to/myfile", "run"`

I know see the program running and stopping on the breakpoint, see the program's output in the integrated terminal and can toggle to the debugging console. But how can I see both the debugging console and the integrated terminal at once?
If somehow possible I'd like to not use an external window for one of those, as there are multiple vscode instances open - each connecting to a different server - and multiple windows "mgically" belonging to each other would make debugging harder together - the integrated option solves this problem completely.

Comment: You can drag one of them to the View Container of the Debugger Bar

Comment: That sounds good. Can you make an answer of this comment, ideally with a picture _how_ to do that?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589066/how-to-keep-terminal-debug-console-and-output-screens-in-simultaneous-view-in-v

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Views and Panels (Problems - Terminal - Output - Debug console) can be moved.

Click on the header/Tab of the View/Panel and drag the mouse to the new location.

The mouse pointer will change if it is possible to drop it.

You can restore a panel/view to the original location from the context menu on the top-bar.

I have looked in the doc but could not find any mentioning of this. It was mentioned in one of the Release notes.

Comment: Screenshot and slightly different wording is found in the answer for the "not found duplicate" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589066, according to the even older duplicate of that question possibly has the release note reference mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65504739/5027456 (it definitely would be nice to have something like this in the official docs...)

Comment: @SimonSobisch I tried the drag/drop and was not able to get it side by side, but you have to drag/drop the not-current tab, you can reset the location with the context menu of the panel

Comment: @SimonSobisch I have created an issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/4362

Comment: I know have it side by side: you currently have to click on the debug-console, drag it to the terminal until its content is shown (still holding the button), then drag it a bit deeper "next to" the terminal and then drop. Result: both side-by-side.

Comment: @SimonSobisch I did not knew this `holding` trick, the wait time is pretty long for me, maybe because I have the hover time setting large.